# Using docker exec with gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have running container inside my gitlab-runner job

docker ps result inside runner:

| CONTAINER ID | IMAGE | COMMAND | CREATED | STATUS | PORTS | NAMES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 244e287642fa | backend-web | "python3 src/manage.…" | 4 seconds ago | Up Less than a second | 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp | backend |

but after command:

`docker exec backend python3 src/manage.py test`

i got next:

`Error response from daemon: Container 244e287642faf27b3d0d4404e0d9558ab935d69f7591f155f6a0e24a81d9628d is not running`

My pipeline:

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"


services:
   - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test


build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose build

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker ps
    - docker exec backend python3 src/manage.py test
```

Comment: maybe add, `docker-compose logs` before `docker ps`, or even remove the `-d` flag to get an actual error log. The problem seems to be that the compose application is running and then failing. I bet if you add sleep command before `docker ps` you will get an empty result as there are no container running.

Comment: Do you want to `docker-compose run` the tests, rather than first trying to start the application and then run the unit tests inside the running application?

Comment: My application starting inside container